# Редирект после basic аутентификации

Tags: redirect, аутентификация, php

Имеется страница, на которой бэйсик аутентификация. Нужно после нажатия "OK" редиректить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как.

Comment: @Vasja Pupkin, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: http://php.net/header

Comment: Я сделал front-end до конца.
А по back-end'у реализовал всё практически тоже,осталось вот авторизацию basic доделать,сделал вывод окошка(требующего логин и пароль),сделал запись логина и md5(пароль) в лог,запись данных в куки,и проверку имеется ли такой логин и пасс(хэш) в логе,нужно теперь после нажатия кнопки ОК в окошке редиректить на следующую страницу.

Comment: логика проста - если к скрипту обратились, а пароля нет - показываем диалог авторизации, если к скрипту обратились, пароль есть и урл тот, с которого отправляют на авторизацию - посылаем команду редиректа. По ссылке выше Вам дали все, что нужно для реализации этого кода.